# How to supply the storage connection string without setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING for azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

In the example I found, you need to setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING for a real environment variable. But Azure function does not have that, only configuration.
I set it in the local.settings.json file but when I run it has an issue with it and the function does not load.

How do I get the connection string to work?

```
[2023-09-12T11:14:30.192Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ContractQueue'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
[2023-09-12T11:14:30.214Z] Error indexing method 'Functions.ContractQueue'
[2023-09-12T11:14:30.218Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ContractQueue'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
[2023-09-12T11:14:30.222Z] Function 'Functions.ContractQueue' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2023-09-12T11:14:30.294Z] The 'ContractQueue' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ContractQueue'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
```

Comment: please share your function code. Are you trying to run the function locally or in portal?

Comment: Also share your local.settings file to help you better

Comment: Got it. "AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", was missing from the settings   Thanks

Comment: AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true is used for local development but you need to pass the storage account connection string in order to get your function triggered when a message will send to the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition to my comment, while creating the azure queue triggered function you will get below options in the function template due to the below item

[image]

If configuration dependencies is ticked, then you will prompted to the following options in next step

[image]

For first two options, you will need to give the connection string as below in your local settings file and in function.cs file and this will use local storage queue emulator.

**local.settings**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**function.cs**

```
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
```

But if you will choose **Azure Storage** option, then it will  show you all the storage account in your subscription. Select one of the storage account and provide the connection string name as below

[image]

Function.cs file will look like below

```
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("input-queue", Connection = "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
```

No need to add `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING` in your local settings file because its already stored in secrets.json file.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Please Note**: You need to use latest package of `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues` and `Azure.Storage.Queues`

Comment: I chose Azure Storage option. That worked but I see in the output " Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'contracts-queue-poison'." But my debugger never gets to the break point.  Can yo tell why?

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#poison-messages for your output message `Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'contracts-queue-poison'`. Regarding debugger issue, I believe function is retrying internally as its an inbuild feature of queue triggered function and if it still fails then function runtime will add the poison message

Comment: Turns out only one combination of packages works:   "Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
  "Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
  "Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.16.0" />
  "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
  "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
  "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />

Comment: Yes, you need to use all the latest packages only

Answer (score 0):

"AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
must be in the in the settings